# wxpython event for panel.Show()

Tags: python, wxpython

I have tried looking through the documentation but not sure which to use.

I am basically looking for an event that is called when the panel containing the event is shown.

My program is split into multiple panels, which the user switches between with buttons. I haven't been able to get the button which switches panels to be able to interact with the combobox, so I've been trying to get it to update when the panel is shown.

```
class SomePanel(wx.Panel):
    ... # Panel initilisation/Event listeners

    def panelShown(self, event):
        # update combobox
```

Edit: I have found it. Leaving question up in case anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with code as weird as mine.

In the SomePanel class:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_SHOW, self.panelShown)
```